# Best way to add high heels to the armature?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I have a character with a flat foot. Now I need to add high heels to the armature and those high heels fit the leg when it is rotated to 30 degrees. At this angle, I could easily weight-paint them to fit the feet. Yet it is not my Rest pose (and for the character the rest pose should be barefoot). So I was wondering what is the best way to skin those high heels to an armature? How can I skin to a specific pose and preserve my original rest pose?

Comment: Nothing forces you to skin your heels model while in rest pose, you can do it in whatever pose you like. I would store the feet's heel pose into the asset library or pose library for convenience, but that's about it.

Comment: Most high heels shouldn't deform, so I would bone parent rather than armature deform.  Separate into left and right shoe objects if necessary; pose the foot bone to match the shoe; *bone parent* the shoe to its foot bone.

Comment: Go to armature modifier and enable two little vertices buttons on the left of enable in viewport and enable in render, so that the modifier is enabled also in edit mode and weight paint mode.